# Any good resources on how to write better in Italian?

Tags: writing, resources

I was wondering if there is are any good (free) resources online for learning how to write or improving written Italian. Most resources that I have found relate to speaking the language. Moocs, books, anything?

Comment: I can't recommend one in particular, but surely *reading* much good italian can help a lot.

Comment: I recommend this site where you can pose your questions directly to Italian mothertongues.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you this site:

> **http://www.busuu.com**

I'm not sure if this resource is nowadays as good as it was in the past because I haven't been using it very much lately and some people told me that it has changed in worse (I don't know if that's true). But I can assure you that my written Italian has improved a lot with it.

It works as a social network of people interested in learning languages. The site proposes you writing exercises that you can submit so that you'll get a correction from a native speaker. Each user of the network is both a student of a foreign language and a "teacher" of its own mother tongue. The interesting fact is that you can make your own circle of reliable Italian friends so as to send them your own written exercises.

Answer (score 2):

I have an amazing and updated suggestion for you that I have recently found out! 
I went to a Professional communication and writing skill class in Milano (università Cattolica) and these were the books that they have suggested.

*Guida di stile*, Luisa Carrada.
*Struttura e sintassi*, Luisa Carrada.

They are extremely easy and accessible, super short and full of immediately actionable advice! These are books that go straight to the point and can improve your writing in Italian substantially.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reading (books, magazines, ...) in Italian.
2. Write something everyday (maybes start a blog/diary in Italian).
3. Specialized books (like *Scrivere bene (o quasi)*. Ortografia, punteggiatura, stile, dubbi, curiosità; by Elisabetta Perini).
4. Get a good tutor/teacher, who can check your text from time to time.